# A finite $H$-module algebra is necessarily inner

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, hopf-algebras

Let $H$ be a finite-dimensional Hopf algebra over a field $k$, and $A$ an $H$-module algebra.

If $A$ is finite-dimensional over $k$, is the action of $H$ on $A$ necessarily inner?

If this is not true in general, is at least true when $H$ is (co)semisimple?

To recall the definition, a (left) action of $H$ on $A$ is *inner* if there exists an invertible $u$ in the convolution algebra $\operatorname{Hom}_k(H,A)$ such that for all $h\in H$ and $a\in A$, $$h\cdot a = \sum u(h_{(1)})au^{-1}(h_{(2)}).$$